# "Best" English translation(s) of Kierkegaard to read?

Tags: kierkegaard, translation

I would like to read a recent (within the last 40 years, preferably) & well-done (stays true to what Kierkegaard communicated given the cultural, philosophical, literature, and religious contexts) English translation of Kierkegaard's works. Not sure yet which book I'll start with, may depend on which works have the best translations.

Any recommendations? If you could provide some background on the translator that could be helpful.

Note: Since I haven't yet read much Kierkegaard, my selection of 'best answer' will be a 'best guess'. Mayhaps I'll revisit this post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hong translations of all of Kierkegaard's works are currently the de facto standard English translations which seek to stay true to the original texts.  Each edition includes massive amounts of footnotes to clarify cultural references and even a lot of Danish wordplay that doesn't otherwise translate well into English.

There have also been several newer translations of individual works that may be more readable if the Hong translations aren't your cup of tea!